# My functions carrying out my calculations are returning 0 every time. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, function, calculator

I'm just trying to get the first calculation to work before I do the rest. But every time it keeps returning 0.
I've tried multiple solutions myself but cannot find anything that works.

My code is listed here:

```
garden_length = 0
garden_width = 0
veg_length = 0
veg_width = 0
flower_length = 0
flower_width = 0
garden_area = 0
veg_area = 0

def GetGardenLength():
    try:
        garden_length = float(input('Please enter the gardens length in metres: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid NUMBER.')
        return GetGardenLength()
    return garden_length

def GetGardenWidth():
    try:
        garden_width = float(input('Please enter the gardens width in metres: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid NUMBER.')
        return GetGardenWidth()
    return garden_width

def GetVegPlotLength():
    try:
        veg_length = float(input('Please enter the vegetable plots length in metres: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid NUMBER.')
        return GetVegPlotLength()

def GetVegPlotWidth():
    try:
        veg_width = float(input('Please enter the vegetable plots width in metres: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid NUMBER.')
        return GetVegPlotWidth()

def GetFlowerLength():
    try:
        flower_length = float(input('Please enter the flower beds length in metres: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid NUMBER.')
        return GetFlowerLength()

def GetFlowerWidth():
    try:
        flower_width= float(input('Please enter the flower beds width in metres: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid NUMBER.')
        return GetFlowerWidth()

def CalculateGardenArea():
    garden_area = (garden_length * garden_width)
    print('The Area of the Garden is ' + str(garden_area))

def CalculateVegArea():
    veg_area = (veg_length * veg_width)
    print('The Area of the Vegetable Plot is ' + str(veg_area))

GetGardenLength()
GetGardenWidth()
GetVegPlotLength()
GetVegPlotWidth()
GetFlowerLength()
GetFlowerWidth()
CalculateGardenArea()
CalculateVegArea()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, assigning to a variable within a function makes it locally scoped, always. To get around this, you need to use the `global` keyword like so:

```
def GetGardenLength():
    global garden_length
    try:
        garden_length = float(input('Please enter the gardens length in metres: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid NUMBER.')
        return GetGardenLength()
    return garden_length
```

Or, since your functions already return a value, just use the return value (without making the above change):

```
garden_length = GetGardenLength()
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions `GetFlowerLength`, `GetVegPlotWidth`, `GetVegPlotLength` and `GetFlowerWidth` don't return a value inside `try` statement.

Your code should look like this (repeat for other functions):

```
def GetVegPlotLength():
    try:
        veg_length = float(input('Please enter the vegetable plots length in metres: '))
        return veg_length # <-- code missing
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid NUMBER.')
        return GetVegPlotLength()
```

Comment: Just to let you know, inline comments in Python use `#` not `//` :)

Comment: @leaf my bad. JS to Python switching problems :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is one of scope. `CalculateGardenArea` doesn't have access to the garden_length and garden_width variables that were defined in the `GetGardenLength` and `GetGardenWidth`. Play around with this code to understand that:

```
def addTwoPrint():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    print (a + b)

def addTwo():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return (a + b)
addTwoPrint()

a = addTwo()
b = addTwo()

print (a + b)
```

And you can update your code to reflect this probably most simply by editing your code like so:

```
def CalculateGardenArea(garden_length, garden_width):
    garden_area = (garden_length * garden_width)
    print('The Area of the Garden is ' + str(garden_area))

gard_len = GetGardenLength()
gard_wid = GetGardenWidth()
CalculateGardenArea(gard_len, gard_wid)
```